# PHP SoapClient and a complex header

Tags: php, soap

I have been trying for a while now, but I can't figure out how to use PHP SoapCLient in combination with a WSDL to form a complex header (that is, more complex than any tutorial I could find). The envelope that I need to send looks like this:

```
(001) <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>

(002) <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

(003) <SOAP-ENV:Header>

(004) <eb:MessageHeader xmlns:eb="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader" eb:version="2.0" SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1">

(005) <eb:From>

(006) <eb:PartyId>webservices.example.com</eb:PartyId> 

(007) </eb:From>

(008) <eb:To>

(009) <eb:PartyId>clientURL</eb:PartyId> 

(010) </eb:To>

(011) <eb:CPAId>IPCC</eb:CPAId> 

(012) <eb:ConversationId>ABC123@clientURL.com</eb:ConversationId> 

(013) <eb:Service eb:type="XML">Session</eb:Service> 

(014) <eb:Action>SessionCreateRS</eb:Action> 

(015) <eb:MessageData>

(016) <eb:MessageId>mid:20030707-12545-1369@webservices.sabre.com</eb:MessageId> 

(017) <eb:Timestamp>2001-02-15T11:25:12Z</eb:Timestamp> 

(018) </eb:MessageData>

(019) <RefToMessageId>mid:20001209-133003-2333@clientURL</RefToMessageId> 

(020) </eb:MessageHeader>

(021) <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext">

(022) <wsse:BinarySecurityToken xmlns:wsu="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/utility" wsu:Id="SabreSecurityToken" valueType="String" EncodingType="wsse:Base64Binary">Shared/IDL:IceSess\/SessMgr:1\.0.IDL/Common/!ICESMS\/RESC!ICESMSLB\/RES.LB!-4954987477210575357!252506!0</wsse:BinarySecurityToken> 

(023) </wsse:Security>

(024) </SOAP-ENV:Header>

(025) <SOAP-ENV:Body>

(026) <eb:Manifest xmlns:eb="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader" eb:version="2.0">

(027) <eb:Reference eb:id="SessionCreateRS" xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="cid:SessionCreateRS"

(028) <eb:Description xml:lang="en-US">Response Message</eb:Description>"/>

(029) </eb:Reference>

(030) </eb:Manifest>

(031) </SOAP-ENV:Body>

(032) </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I tried to make it using __setSoapHeaders() and using SoapVar(). I can't get the right output though. From examples I learned it would be good to use a class to fill the parameters in the XML, so I made an class like this:

```
class EbXmlMessage{
 public $From = array('PartyId' => 'www.example.com@example.com');
 public $To = array('PartyId' => 'example.com');
 public $CPAId = 'XXXX';
 public $ConversationId = '12345@example.com';
 public $Service = 'Session';
 public $Action = 'SessionCreateRQ';
 public $MessageData = array( 'MessageId' => "mid:12345@example.com",'Timestamp' => '2010-11-26T08:19:00Z');
}
```

than I use:

```
$eb_params = new SoapVar($eb,SOAP_ENC_OBJECT);
$header =  new SoapHeader($ns,"header", $eb_params,true);
```

But the request does not even slightly begin to look like it has to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2002/11" xmlns:ns2="https://cert.webservices.sabre.com/cert">
 <SOAP-ENV:Header>
  <ns2:header SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1">
   <From>
    <item>
     <key>PartyId</key>
     <value>www.example.com@example.com</value>
    </item>
   </From>
   <To>
    <item>
     <key>PartyId</key>
     <value>webservices.sabre.com</value>
    </item>
   </To>
   <CPAId>XXX</CPAId>
   <ConversationId>12345@example.com</ConversationId>
   <Service>Session</Service>
   <Action>SessionCreateRQ</Action>
   <MessageData>
    <item>
     <key>MessageId</key>
     <value>mid:12345@www.example.com</value>
    </item>
    <item>
     <key>Timestamp</key>
     <value>2010-11-26T08:19:00Z</value>
    </item>
   </MessageData>
  </ns2:header>
 </SOAP-ENV:Header>
 <SOAP-ENV:Body>
  <ns1:SessionCreateRQ>
   <ns1:POS>
    <ns1:Source PseudoCityCode="XXXX"/>
   </ns1:POS>
  </ns1:SessionCreateRQ>
  <param1/>
 </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope
```

The main problems so far are getting the right tags in the XML on the right place, and I don't know how I can get "eb:" and "wsse:" namespace in the tags. I am hoping to use the SoapClientI() class but I'm not sure if it can handle a more complex XML like the one I need, if not maybe I should use Curl or something similar and just treat the XML as a string?

Comment: mangling the string manually is inadvisable as it gets hard to maintain. if you can get the client to work right against the wsdl, even in consideration of weird namespace issues, then it will probably be worth the time.

Answer (score 10):

I had issues with this as well when implementing wsse. Here was my approach. Yes, this is quite wsse-specific; however, it should work in your context as well. Note especially how there's the 'wsse' namespace parameter in the call to `new SoapHeader()`. Just replace that with 'eb' for your case.

```
$header_part = '
    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2003/06/secext" SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1">
        <wsse:UsernameToken>
            <wsse:Username>'."USERNAME".'</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password>'."PASSWORD".'</wsse:Password>
        </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
';
$soap_var_header = new SoapVar( $header_part, XSD_ANYXML, null, null, null );
$soap_header = new SoapHeader( 'http://your-target-service.com', 'wsse', $soap_var_header );
$soap_client->__setSoapHeaders($soap_header);
```

Another solution is to mangle the XML after subclassing the SoapClient, but I'd only do this as a last resort.

```
class My_SoapClient extends SoapClient {
   protected $_response = null;
   public function __doRequest( $request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way=null ) {
      // insert big bad mangling code here
      $this->_response = parent::__doRequest( $this->_request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way );
      return $this->_response;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible way of doing this is overwriting the `__doRequest` function using `curl`. There is an example [here](http://www.xdevsoftware.com/blog/post/Set-KeepAlive-Header-in-PHP-SoapClient.aspx) which shows how to turn off `KeepAlive`.