# soapheader authenticate using php

Tags: php, soap, soap-client, soapheader

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP SoapClient and a complex header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4319088/php-soapclient-and-a-complex-header)

I have this header structure:

```
<soapenv:Header>
  <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse=”http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd” soapenv:mustUnderstand=”0”>
    <wsse:UsernameToken>
    <wsse:Username Type=”http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#UsernameToken”>votre_login</wsse:Username>
    <wsse:Password Type=”http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText”>votre_password</wsse:Password>
    </wsse:UsernameToken>
  </wsse :Security>
</soapenv :Header>
```

How I put this in php using `__setSoapHeaders()` method?

I tried:

```
$auth = array(
            'UsernameToken' => array(
                'Username' => '*****',
                'Password' => '*****'
            )
        );
$header = new SoapHeader('http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd','Security',$auth, 0);
$client->__setSoapHeaders($header);
```

and I have this error:

> com.ibm.wsspi.wssecurity.SoapSecurityException: WSEC5509E: Un jeton de
>   sécurité dont le type est
>   [http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#UsernameToken]
>   est requis.

Comment: This solution [PHP SoapClient and a complex header](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4319088/php-soapclient-and-a-complex-header) working for me, but is not elegant, I try to build this header using php arrays or objects.

Answer (score 4):

From: http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.setsoapheaders.php#93460

> To create complex SOAP Headers, you can do something like this:
>
> Required SOAP Header:
>
> ```
> <soap:Header> 
>  <RequestorCredentials xmlns="http://namespace.example.com/"> 
>   <Token>string</Token> 
>   <Version>string</Version> 
>   <MerchantID>string</MerchantID> 
>   <UserCredentials> 
>    <UserID>string</UserID> 
>    <Password>string</Password> 
>   </UserCredentials> 
>  </RequestorCredentials> 
> </soap:Header>
> ```
>
> Corresponding PHP code:
>
> ```
> $ns = 'http://namespace.example.com/'; //Namespace of the WS. 
>
> //Body of the Soap Header. 
> $headerbody = array('Token' => $someToken, 
>                 'Version' => $someVersion, 
>                 'MerchantID'=>$someMerchantId, 
>                   'UserCredentials'=>array('UserID'=>$UserID, 
>                                          'Password'=>$Pwd)); 
>
> //Create Soap Header.        
> $header = new SOAPHeader($ns, 'RequestorCredentials', $headerbody);        
>
> //set the Headers of Soap Client. 
> $soap_client->__setSoapHeaders($header);
> ```

Comment: Not working for me. My header seems to be more complex...