# Basic auth with php soap

Tags: php, soap

I'm trying to connect to a soap server that use a Basic Authentication with PHP7

With this example, the login and password are not send in the header.

Do I miss something ?

Code:

```
$options = [];
$options['login'] = $authentication->getLogin();
$options['password'] = $authentication->getPassword();
$options['authentication'] = SOAP_AUTHENTICATION_BASIC;

$client =  new SoapClient($wsdl, $options);
$client->__soapCall($functionName, $arguments);
```

Header send:

```
POST /V4/services/ServerAPI HTTP/1.1 Host:
serverurl.com Connection: Keep-Alive User-Agent: PHP
version: PHP SDK 4.52.1 Content-Type: application/soap+xml;
charset=utf-8; action="test" Content-Length: 6904
```

Normally i should see something like

```
Basic authentication: mybase64
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4319088/php-soapclient-and-a-complex-header

Comment: I want to use Basic auth (header) not wsse or anything in SoapHeader ;)

Answer (score 0):

$authentication->getLogin() return an integer. Cast with string solve the issue.

```
$options['login'] = (string) $authentication->getLogin();
```